# Get O365 group calendar edit event URL

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api

If you open an event from a Group Calendar using the Outlook Web App, there is an option in the right corner of edit page to "pop out" the editor into a new window.

Is it possible to retrieve this edit mode url through Microsoft Graph?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible. The Outlook Web App is a separate application and is not extensible or addressable from the Microsoft Graph API. Graph would simple facilitate retrieving and saving of event data using your own application.